# Why do these textures tile rather than just overlap?

Tags: unity, scripting

It might help to provide all the details, so here is the [YouTube tutorial which sparked my question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAfZ5gFaThI).

There's a prefab of the background tile called "Tile Background." This prefab has the default settings, except that `Pixels Per Unit` is set to 512, and that it has a script attached to it called `BackgroundTile` which hasn't even been opened. It's just there for the other script to reference.

An empty object was created called `Board`, which has Tile Background as its tile prefab. It also has a script, `Board.cs`, the contents of which are [here](https://pastebin.com/CPbmAUh9):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public GameObject tilePrefab;
    private Backgroundtile[,] allTiles;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        allTiles = new Backgroundtile[width,height];
        Setup();
    }

    private void Setup() {
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(i, j);
                Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Width is set to 4. Height is set to 7.
 
Other than that, the camera position is X:1.5,Y:3 and the aspect ratio is 9:16.

My question is this: why, when this is run, does `Vector2(i,j)` get interpreted as tiling the sprites, rather than placing the sources of the sprites in a 4x7 pixel grid, where they overlap almost entirely? There's no place where their positions get multiplied by the size of the tiles, right? Halving the pixels per unit doesn't even just halve the height of the board - it stays a constant size and looks really weird, despite the board not having set dimension attributes.

What's going on here?

Comment: I didn't take a deep look at this, so I might be wrong, but it looks like the setup is such that the position is specified in world-space coordinates (and not screen-space or pixels); furthermore, the `Instantiate` method takes a `Vector3` for the position parameter, with `tempPosition` being implicitly converted.

Comment: How do I change the properties of world space then, and why did it happen to line up with 512 pixel squares in this example? That can't actually be a coincidence.

Comment: @Somniad The squares aren't 512 pixels wide and tall, their texture is. You need to separate texture sizes from the 3d units in your mind. A 1x1 unit square can have any texture size.